# Calling "[self.view release];" stops memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, viewcontroller

I'm quite new to Objective-C, and whilst I think I understand the basics of reference counting, I'm not understanding some of the behaviour I'm seeing.

In Instruments, I've noticed that I'm leaking memory quite badly when moving between 2 ViewControllers. As far as I can tell I'm calling release every time I call alloc, but I'm sure I'm making some rookie mistakes.

However, I found earlier that calling:

```
 [self.view release];
```

Stops the leak. It does however add an error the output log for "pointer being freed was not allocated". Obviously this is fixing something that I've done wrong, but I'm not sure why calling it there is doing the job that

```
[super dealloc];
```

Should (?) be doing.

I'm sure it's full of problems, but if anyone could help I'd be really grateful- been tearing my hair out with this for a few days :/

Here's the code for the WatchViewController:

```
#import "WatchViewController.h"

@implementation WatchViewController

@synthesize backButton = _backButton, scrollView = _scrollView, image;

...

-(void) backButtonPressed
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

...

- (void)loadView
{
UIView *locView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view = locView;

[locView release];
}

-(void) dealloc
{
self.image = nil;
self.backButton = nil;
self.scrollView = nil;

[super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"back_button" ofType:@"png"];
UIButton *locButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIImage *locImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str];
[locButton setImage:locImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[locButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, locImage.size.width, locImage.size.height)];
[locButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.backButton = locButton;
[self.view addSubview:_backButton];

[locImage release];
[locButton release];

[self.view release];
}
```

Comment: should be self.view = nil, and certainly not in your viewDidLoad, but you are right in that this would be happening in [super dealloc].